# Workaround for anchor tags with href='#' in angular having events bound in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angular

I have an Angular 7.1.1 app using an accordion component based in CSS & jQuery from a third party template designer. The issue I'm facing is that the angular router is navigating to the application root every time the user clicks on the anchor tags (to display accordion content), instead of staying in the same route and trigger the click event on the jQuery script.

I'm asking for a workaround, [since this is a known issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/7294), however there's still no definitive response from the angular team. I have tried the following but the results are still the same, or the click event in jQuery are not getting triggered:

- `href`
- `href=""`
- `href="javascript:void(0);"`

Below the html code from the component template:

```
<div class="accordion accordion-style-0">
    <div class="accordion-border">
        <a href="#" class="font-14" data-accordion="accordion-11"><i class="fa fa-location-arrow"></i>Direccion del Servicio<i class="fa fa-arrow-down "></i></a>
        <div class="accordion-content" id="accordion-11" style="display: none;">
            <p class="bottom-10">{{resultadoConsulta.direccionServicio}}</p>
        </div>
    </div>
<div class="accordion-border">
        <a href="#" class="font-14" data-accordion="accordion-22"><i class="fa fa-list-ol"></i>Detalle de Facturas<i class="fa fa-arrow-down"></i></a>
        <div class="accordion-content" id="accordion-22" style="display: none;">
            <table class="table-borders-dark shadow-small">
                <tbody><tr>
                  <th>Factura</th>
                  <th>Vence en</th>
                  <th>Monto Deuda</th>

                </tr>
                <tr *ngFor="let fac of resultadoConsulta.facturas">
                  <td>{{fac.idFactura}}</td>
                  <td>{{fac.fechaEmision | date:'dd/MMM/yy' }}</td>
                  <td style="text-align: right; padding-right: 12px;">{{fac.montoAdeudado | currency }}</td>
                </tr>

              </tbody></table>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: should you be using jquery with angular?  I thought they don't play well together

Comment: @Pete, the issue here is more about how to handle the anchor tags with an href value of "#", than about the compatibility of jQuery and Angular. Be aware that even without using jQuery this issue arises in simple html.